# Setting a cron job in cpanel to transfer file between remote servers

Tags: wordpress, ftp, cron, wget, file-transfer

I am currently trying to automate the our online store so that orders from our system get put into our logistics company's server. At the moment, our orders automatically go into a folder called 'automated-orders' on our server through a wordpress plugin. I cannot get this plugin to directly interact with the logistics server.

The goal:

To get a file (.csv file) in our 'automated-orders' folder to automatically (every night) be copied from a directory on our cpanel hosted web server to a ftp location on our logistics company website. Their server requires a login and password. There are some days where there may not be any order files so in this case it will just do nothing. Ideally, it will scan to see if there are any new files before doing the transfer.

I have been looking through these forums and others about cron jobs and wget and wput but don't think I have the syntax right as nothing happens. This is what I have as our cron line command:

```
wget /home/rhinospo/public_html/automated-orders --ftp-user=RH1 --password='PASSWORD' ftp://RH1@182.50.154.233/RH1/Incoming
```

Could someone please see what I am doing wrong in this syntax. Alternatively, is there another/better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Cheers

Comment: I have just seen the results of the automation emailed (though they went to my spam folder so missed them before my post).

`code`
/home/rhinospo/public_html/automated-orders: Scheme missing.
--2015-12-29 10:45:01--  ftp://RH1@182.50.154.233/RH1/Incoming
           => “Incoming”
Connecting to 182.50.154.233:21... connected.
Logging in as RH1 ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /RH1 ... done.
==> SIZE Incoming ... done.
==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR Incoming ...
No such file “Incoming”.
`code`

Comment: So it looks like the automation is happening but I don't have the file being found or transferred correctly.. Do I need to specify the file itself? (and can this be done with a * since each day the file name is different)

wget /home/rhinospo/public_html/automated-orders/*.csv?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl for this chase

```
curl -T /home/rhinospo/public_html/automated-orders ftp://182.50.154.233/RH1/Incoming --user RH1:password
```